# how to update a array of objects in jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Need help: Beginner

how to update the backgroundColor item of the event array? i am trying this but is not working.
please help

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {        
        data[key].backgroundColor === '#F79475';
    });
```

data is a array of objects as

allDay: true
backgroundColor: "#5173CA"
end: "2013-10-25T00:00:00"
id: 1
start: "2013-10-21T00:00:00"
title: "xyz"
userId: 2

Comment: `===` is a comparison, you probably wanted `=` which is an assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry got it

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {        
    data[key].backgroundColor = '#F79475';
});
```

Comment: Note also, inside of the callback function, you can use `this` instead of `data[key]` and then omit the two function parameters.